# is NSString mutableCopy make memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

[image]

What is the problem?

could you solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you think there is a memory leak?

Comment: i think that has no problem. but when i run profile the app i saw memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It's immediately autoreleased, so I don't think that's where the problem is. It's probably retained somewhere else, and never released. Profile the app with leaks enabled to see a list of every retain and release against that object.